# The Server Instance is Blank

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-nav

I am trying to connect into the sql server but the server instance is blank I already try to search a instance but is not appearing nothing

Below are the pictures:

Database Information

[image]

Available Server Instances

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This means that none Nav servers are started

Answer (score 0):

Check that your service points to the correct database